# Openpyxl: Worksheet has no object delete rows error

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am fairly new to python and working my way through the openpyxl package within python and I am unable to get the delete_rows function to work? It is saying that the function "delete rows" isnt within workbook?

My code is below:

```
    from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook


data = 'DATA PATH'

wb = load_workbook(filename=data)
sheet1 = wb['Sheet1']

sheet1.delete_rows(idx=3, amount = 5)

wb.save(filename="TEST.xlsx")
```

Any advice would be great and if anymore info behind the question is required just let me know.

Thanks!

(Code has been updated)

Comment: You should not be using `Workbook` on the LHS of the assignment operator. You're overwriting the openpyxl Workbook class this way. if you do `wb = load_workbook(...)` and then `sheet1 = wb['Sheet1']` (this is the preferred way to get worksheet instance) does the same error occur?

Comment: Thanks for that! Of course I am, cant believe I didn't see that! Im now getting the error " 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'delete_rows'"? I have started this on a new project and re-imported the package so the previous error isn't occuring

Comment: can you update your question to include the code in its current state?

Comment: I have updated the code